# Visual Studio Command line argument fields replaced with application arguments

Tags: visual-studio

I've always been using the command line arguments field in project properties > debug to step through and debug my software. but recently i cant seem to access the field no more.

instead i've got "application arguments"
[image]

however when i try to run the software with the new args in the "application arguments" i'm getting both the old args i had in the old "command line arguments" and the new set. which is not what i want. anyone knows how i can access the previous args to delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a file [ProjectName.csproj.user] which is an xml file where .net stored the debug information. i was able to delete the previous args from
 to resolve the issue.

hopefully this helps someone in the future